# Elastic Search Aggregation with bool query

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my elastic bool query. this works fine :

```
{
  "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "parent_uuid._raw": [
                            "87ec596a-109e-45ce-8a8d-7a2d1a56df81",
                            "07526608-8140-46be-96b9-c5f7cca4bd93"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "resource_type._raw": [
                            "Zone"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "from": 0
}
```

I want aggregation on name field. So I add this :

```
"aggs": {
    "group_by_name": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "display_name.keyword"
        }
    } }
```

But result is same.
What I am missing?

The result I get is :

> {   "device-resource": [
>       {
>         "fq_name": [
>           "default-domain",
>           "muthu1500",
>           "EP",
>           "JUNOS/Zone=oam"
>         ],
>         "uuid": "161cf82d-16fd-4219-861d-d50de622f8eb",
>         "uri": "/ems-central/device-resource/161cf82d-16fd-4219-861d-d50de622f8eb"
>       },
>       {
>         "fq_name": [
>           "default-domain",
>           "muthu1500",
>           "EP",
>           "JUNOS/Zone=untrust"
>         ],
>         "uuid": "fe28fb7c-c087-4473-aeef-e302022f47a4",
>         "uri": "/ems-central/device-resource/fe28fb7c-c087-4473-aeef-e302022f47a4"
>       },
>       {
>         "fq_name": [
>           "default-domain",
>           "muthu1500",
>           "MNONZT",
>           "JUNOS/Zone=trust"
>         ],
>         "uuid": "251a4a9e-acb4-49ed-9c29-499ddbceb532",
>         "uri": "/ems-central/device-resource/251a4a9e-acb4-49ed-9c29-499ddbceb532"
>       },
>       {
>         "fq_name": [
>           "default-domain",
>           "muthu1500",
>           "MNONZT",
>           "JUNOS/Zone=untrust"
>         ],
>         "uuid": "a3417512-8953-4c1e-b68e-8390327d5213",
>         "uri": "/ems-central/device-resource/a3417512-8953-4c1e-b68e-8390327d5213"
>       },
>       {
>         "fq_name": [
>           "default-domain",
>           "muthu1500",
>           "SRX1500MD",
>           "JUNOS/Zone=trust"
>         ],
>         "uuid": "1a5434c5-d47d-40be-bb00-ef1d244e6c0c",
>         "uri": "/ems-central/device-resource/1a5434c5-d47d-40be-bb00-ef1d244e6c0c"
>       }   ],   "total": 5 }

Since last two records have same display_name as 2nd and 3rd record respectively, aggregate should show only 1 of them.
I want this result:

> {   "device-resource": [
>       {
>         "fq_name": [
>           "default-domain",
>           "muthu1500",
>           "EP",
>           "JUNOS/Zone=oam"
>         ],
>         "uuid": "161cf82d-16fd-4219-861d-d50de622f8eb",
>         "uri": "/ems-central/device-resource/161cf82d-16fd-4219-861d-d50de622f8eb"
>       },
>       {
>         "fq_name": [
>           "default-domain",
>           "muthu1500",
>           "EP",
>           "JUNOS/Zone=untrust"
>         ],
>         "uuid": "fe28fb7c-c087-4473-aeef-e302022f47a4",
>         "uri": "/ems-central/device-resource/fe28fb7c-c087-4473-aeef-e302022f47a4"
>       },
>       {
>         "fq_name": [
>           "default-domain",
>           "muthu1500",
>           "MNONZT",
>           "JUNOS/Zone=trust"
>         ],
>         "uuid": "251a4a9e-acb4-49ed-9c29-499ddbceb532",
>         "uri": "/ems-central/device-resource/251a4a9e-acb4-49ed-9c29-499ddbceb532"
>       }   ],   "total": 3 }

Comment: The result is the same as what? You have 10 hits and then at the bottom the aggregation results. If you want to get rid of the hits, just set `"size": 0`

Comment: @Val the aggregation is not working. Result with aggs and w/o aggs are same

Comment: Can you share your index mapping?

Comment: "display_name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "_lowercase": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
            },
            "_raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },

Comment: "resource_type": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "_lowercase": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
            },
            "_raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }

Comment: "parent_uuid": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "_lowercase": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "case_insensitive"
            },
            "_raw": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }

Comment: @Val Please see mappings in above comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your mapping, your `terms` aggregation needs to be like this (use the `_raw` sub-field):

```
"aggs": {
  "group_by_name": {
    "terms": {
        "field": "display_name._raw"
    }
} }
```

Comment: same result, not aggregating

Comment: Did you add the `_raw` sub-field after having indexed your data? i.e. did you modify the mapping after ingesting data?

Comment: No, I have not modified the mapping.

Comment: Do you have have hits in the response?

Comment: Can you run this `POST your_index_name/_update_by_query` and run the search query again afterwards?

Comment: I do not have access to change mapping/index.

Comment: That command doesn't change the mapping, but simply reindexes the data to make sure that the `_raw` field is populated

Comment: It is populated, I tried filter on _raw field, it filters properly. Only issue is aggs not working
  {
                    "terms" :{
                        "display_name._raw" : ["JUNOS/Zone=oam"]
                    }
                }

Comment: By "not working" do you mean there are no buckets or not the ones you expect?

Comment: It does not remove duplicate data (results having same display_name )

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample response you get please and what you expect instead?

Comment: @Val Edited the question with the expected response.

Comment: I'm sorry but the data you're showing doesn't really correspond to the mapping you've shared. Where is `device_resource` ? what that field mapping? Is that a nested field?

Comment: I was using a wrapper API to send this query, seems like that wrapper API is not acknowledging the aggs. Thanks for your input about _raw, I tried that directly on index it worked.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!